# Move partition to another disk

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage, partition

Looking to move a partition on Disk 0 (E:) to Disk 3. Reason for doing so is that I want to extend the Disk 0 (C:) partition and I want both drives/partitions on separate VMDK's.

Disk 0 and Disk 3 are 2 separate VMDK's on an ESXi hypervisor.

Our DFS folder structure is contained on E: and I would like to move all of this data to Disk 3, also using E: and retaining all file/folder security permissions and shares.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've read about third party partition tools such as AOMEI Partition Assistant and Paragon Partition Manager; and I've used Gparted in the past but I do not want to power down the VM to accomplish this. I also want the move to be seamless so DFS isn't affected and is unaware of the change.

[image: disks]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method or tool that I'm aware of that can move a partition/volume to another disk.

What you can do is to use something like Robocopy to copy the data with the permissions from one volume to the other. Then coordinate/schedule a cutover. When you perform the cutover you can simply unshare the folders on the source volume and reshare them on the destination volume. To make that simpler you can export the shared folders from the registry, edit the reg file accordingly for the new location, and import the edited reg file. That will make the share changes for you, including the share permissions.